# vue: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I upgraded my project from webpack3.x to webpack4.28.4,when I run the webpack for production it shows error to me!

```js
ERROR in ./src/router/_import_production.js 9:11
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (9:11)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| module.exports = function (file) {
|   return function () {
>     return import("@/views/" + file + ".vue");
|   };
| };
 @ ./src/router/index.js 8:14-58
 @ ./src/main.js
```

I used happypack to increase compile speed!

```js
const HappyPack = require('happypack')
const os = require('os')
const happyThreadPool = HappyPack.ThreadPool({
    size: os.cpus().length
})
```

```js
{
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: vueLoaderConfig
},
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    use: 'happypack/loader?id=babel',
    include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test'), resolve('node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client')]
}
```

```js
new HappyPack({
    id: 'babel',
    loaders: [{
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
            cacheDirectory: true
        }
    }],
    threadPool: happyThreadPool,
    verbose: true
})
```

It did't work!can anyone fix my problem?Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

_import_production.js  modify this file

```
module.exports = file => require('@/views/' + file + '.vue').default
```